# how to stop the code for the user to enter the following value in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do some calculator and want user take turns input first and second value. I need stop program when user enter first value and continue when user enter second value in the same input field. User continues by pressing the "=" button in html code or "Enter".

```
$('#plus').on('click', function(){
    var firstNum = $("#txt").val()
    $("input").val('')
    if (isResult === true || $("input").keypress() === 13){
        var secondNum = $("#txt").val()
        result = Number(firstNum)+Number(secondNum)
        console.log(result) 
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txt' value='' onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter number" />
```

Comment: That's not the way web applications work. You don't stop the program, the program reacts to events that the user triggers with their actions.

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow.  your question could be made easier to answer if you provide more code - we need a minimal, reproducible example and some details about the output or errors you see.  For more info on a minimal reproducible example, give this post a read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript programs don't stop to wait for the user, they react to events that are triggered asynchronously by the user.

You can save the state of the program in a global variable between calls to the event handler.

```js
var firstNum;

$('#plus').on('click', function() {
  if (firstNum === undefined) {
    firstNum = Number($("#txt").val());
  } else {
    var secondNum = Number($("#txt").val());
    var result = firstNum + secondNum;
    console.log(result);
  }
  $("#txt").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txt' value='' onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter number" />
<button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the second input element(and equal button) hidden when the page loads and then show the input(and equal button) when the operator is clicked by the user to make it more interactive.

You can get more information about toggling between hiding and showing an element on this astonishing website: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

```js
var firstNum;
var secondNum;

var first_in = document.getElementById("txt1");
var sec_in = document.getElementById("txt2");
var equal = document.getElementById("equals");
sec_in.style.display = "none";
equal.style.display = "none";

$('#plus').on('click', function() {
  if (firstNum === undefined) {
    firstNum = Number($("#txt1").val());
    sec_in.style.display = "block";
    equal.style.display = "block";
  } 
});

$('#equals').on('click', function() {
  if (secondNum === undefined) {
    secondNum = Number($("#txt2").val());
    var result = firstNum + secondNum;
    console.log(result);
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txt1' value='' onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter first number" />
<button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
<input type='text' id='txt2' value='' onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter second number" />
<button type="button" id="equals">=</button>
```